# Font sizes in Telerik controls

Tags: telerik

What's the easiest way to set the font sizes for ALL telerik control to a single value? I believe you can control fonts by modifying the CC of a specific control, but that's a pain because  I am using many different control types...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to set the font size of all different telerik controls at once, but what you can do is create a [theme and a skin file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx), where you can set the font size for each telerik control.

E.g. create a file `app_themes/my_theme/telerik.skin` and add a skin definition for each control to it:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" Font-Size="12px" />
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" Font-Size="12px" />
and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using one of the default skins.

You will have to go into the Skins directory of every different type of Telerik control you are using and adjust the font size in the Styles.css file.

Answer (score 0):

`<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller"></telerik:RadGrid>`
or use [style builder](http://stylebuilder.telerik.com/) or generate new skin or modify existing.